# No inbound connections on my bitcoin full node with TOR

Tags: full-node, tor

Can someone connect to my running node? u3ob433qu3ebkmsu.onion:8333

I'm behind a [CG-NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT) so I've thought using TOR would solve my problem.

I had my node running for hours but no inbound connections.

`grep debug.log -e inbound` returns nothing.

**$ bitcoin-cli getnetworkinfo**

```
{
  "version": 180000,
  "subversion": "/Satoshi:0.18.0/",
  "protocolversion": 70015,
  "localservices": "000000000000040c",
  "localrelay": true,
  "timeoffset": 0,
  "networkactive": true,
  "connections": 10,
  "networks": [
    {
      "name": "ipv4",
      "limited": true,
      "reachable": false,
      "proxy": "127.0.0.1:9050",
      "proxy_randomize_credentials": true
    },
    {
      "name": "ipv6",
      "limited": true,
      "reachable": false,
      "proxy": "127.0.0.1:9050",
      "proxy_randomize_credentials": true
    },
    {
      "name": "onion",
      "limited": false,
      "reachable": true,
      "proxy": "127.0.0.1:9050",
      "proxy_randomize_credentials": true
    }
  ],
  "relayfee": 0.00001000,
  "incrementalfee": 0.00001000,
  "localaddresses": [
    {
      "address": "u3ob433qu3ebkmsu.onion",
      "port": 8333,
      "score": 4
    }
  ],
  "warnings": ""
}
```

**bitcoin.conf**

```
server=1
daemon=1

# RPC
rpcuser=*****
rpcpassword=*******

# TOR
onlynet=onion
proxy=127.0.0.1:9050
bind=127.0.0.1
dnsseed=0
dns=0
addnode=nkf5e6b7pl4jfd4a.onion
addnode=yu7sezmixhmyljn4.onion

# Raspberry Pi optimizations
dbcache=100
maxorphantx=10
maxmempool=50
maxconnections=40
maxuploadtarget=5000
prune=6000
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It generally takes a long time before the network "discovers" you're a good peer to connect to. It may be a few days before you get inbound connections.

I'm able to connect to you.

Comment: Nice. WIll leave it then for now and will come back in few days to see how it is. Btw, shouldn't I see "inbound" connections on my log? Because I still don't see it.

Comment: Try `getpeerinfo`. Do you see a connection with `"inbound" : true` there?

Comment: yes! there are many

Comment: That means you have many incoming connections.